# Mustard Flavor disappears

Tags: sauce, mustard

I make my macaroni salad with mayonnaise and mustard, but the mustard flavor always disappears so I have to add more.

Why does the mustard flavor disappear?

Answer (score 1):

The flavour of water-based mustard reaches its peak about 15 minutes after you make it. After that it declines quite rapidly. If you're making fresh, then you really should make just enough for 'today'.
The predominant 'hit' of mustard is very volatile & will quickly dissipate.

Store-bought mustard is vinegar- & oil-based, which makes the flavour last longer, but at a loss to the overall mustard hit.
It shouldn't degrade in anything like the short time water-based does… it will be as bland tomorrow as it was today ;)

Comment: I use store bought yellow mustard and after an hour or two the mustard flavor is gone ;and I have to add more

Comment: Maybe the type you use is still almost 'real' & volatile. That or you need to define 'flavour' more carefully.

Comment: The taste of the mustard.  You don't know what mustard tastes like?

Comment: I know exactly what mustard tastes like… but which mustard? Premium Colman's English Mustard powder, or that glowing yellow stuff McDonald's dares to call mustard? The only qualities the two share are the name. if you can't describe what you mean without getting defensive, there's not a lot further this QA can go.

Comment: It is Gulden's American Bold Yellow Mustard  sorry if I was defensive.

Comment: It's not a brand I've heard of, so I don't know its flavour profile or how that changes over time. Store bought stuff should be pretty stable, as it's got to last weeks or months.

Comment: A late thought - do you make this warm then allow to cool? 'Salad' implies cold, but macaroni doesn't start out cold...

Comment: I let the macaroni cool before I add the dressing